# what is the difference of post_type and meta_key in wp?

Tags: wordpress

What is the different between meta_key of wp_postmeta table and post_type of wp_posts table?

Are they related to each other or they are totally 2 different thing?

Thanks

Comment: post_type is always a post type, i.e. attachment, post, page, navigation item etc... meta data can be anything related to the post i.e. custom fields. Your question doesn't really make sense, the 2 things are completely different.

Comment: why we use both of them?

Comment: They do different things... maybe try reading the documentation. [post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) vs. [post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)

Comment: suppose if i have a post with Post Type: 'Page', it means that post hold and display data using Page method and what is the meaning of having meta-data key let us suppose price of that page item

Comment: meta key is it just like adding new field in wp_post table? is it just like post_title and other field of wp_post?